# Go analogue of Python's fileinput.input()?

Tags: go

Is there a Go analogue of Python's [fileinput.input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)?

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

That lets your program work like`grep`, ie. it can read either from a files specified from the commald line `program input.txt` or from standard input `cat input.txt | program`.

Perl's diamond operator `<>` and Ruby's ARGF are similar.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options. Although the `fileinput.input()` function will also check `sys.args[1:]` for any file names, I'm going to focus on reading from stdin here.

Use [`Scanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner). Example from the docs (http://play.golang.org/p/_Nar8-uBDs):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) // Println will add back the final '\n'
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}
```

A lower-level alternative would be `bufio.Reader` with its [`ReadString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) method (http://play.golang.org/p/h2sobrWNYd):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    rbuf := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        line, err := rbuf.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Print(line)
        if err != nil {
            // line contains the last remaining characters or is empty
            // it is only empty if '\n' was the last character in the input
            break
        }
    }
}
```

For the lowest-level alternative, see [`ReadLine()`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadLine).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no Go analogue of that in the standard library. However, reading stding or a named file is only a handful of lines ([example](https://github.com/cznic/golex/blob/master/main.go#L95))